# Can you replace glue with a box, after it's been set?

Tags: boxes, glue

The question is as asked. My intended use case for this would be to have something like minipage, but whose height can be set using glue, rather than only a dimen.

When the page is pretty easy to split up, I can just use `\textheight` to divide things, but sometimes there's extra text on the page, and what I really want to instruct TeX to do is just how to use the remaining space on the page, aside from the stuff I've already typed. I figure the way to do this is to put glue between boxes where content would've gone, and once the glue's been set, replace the glue with a box of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly but using etex you can measure where the glue went and make a box of the same size on the next run:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{\gdef\string#1{\the\pdflastypos}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ZZZZ}

zzzz
\[z=z\]
zzz

\noindent\zz{\zzA}\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0){%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]%
[\dimexpr\ifx\zzA\undefined\textheight\else
 \zzA sp - \zzB sp -2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\fi\relax]%
{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
zzz zzz
\end{minipage}}}
\end{picture}
\vspace{\fill}

zz\zz{\zzB} zzzz 
\begin{itemize}
\item zzzz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I saw an answer like this somewhere else, and I kinda didn't like it. Is there a way to do this without two passes, and without writing the dimension to an output file? Like, perhaps I could save a box in a box register, set it's glue while it's still in the register, and then programatically manipulate the contents of the box later?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk basically, no.:-)

Comment: Well... shucks. I'm gonna hold out hope, though. Maybe another answer will come through. Who knows. I'm not sure how familiar you are with LuaTeX, but if you are, would it expose some functionality that could help me create a command to do this?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk ah now luatex that's a rather different beast. In luatex you could hook in to the output routine and add the box into the middle of the box being shipped out rather than write the coordinates and add it next time. (although doing `\(pdf)savepos` version as here is likely to be easier.)

Comment: In the arguments to your minipage, what is `sp`? Is that a unit of some kind?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk yes it is the fundamental unit for all tex dimensions: scaled point  65536sp=1pt

Comment: Were the picture environment and fbox necessary, or was that just to display the boundaries of the box?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk fbox was just to show it was a box, you need _something_ like a 0,0 picture (but `\smash` would work ) as you need to hide the size of the box so that it has zero size so the glue can stretch as if it wasn't there.

Comment: Okay. I may want to expand on this, so I'd like to double-check my understanding. The `\zz` macro writes `\gdef\zzA{xx.xxx}` (where the x are digits) to the document's aux file. `\zzA` keeps track of where the glue starts, and `\zzB` keeps track of where the glue ends. In your conditional (`\ifx`), you check if `\zzA` is undefined, and consider that sufficient to decide that `\zzB` is undefined as well. When the top/bottom markers are undefined, you use `\textheight` as the minipage's height.

Comment: Here are the things I'm not sure about: in the `\zz` macro, do `\string#1` and `\the\pdflastypos` get expanded/replaced before `\write` happens (I assume \write is a primitive, which means it's more of a command/function)? How tall is the minipage on the first go? It looks like it has height `\textheight`. Does the `\begin{picture}(0,0)` sort of offset that, placing a huge box in a box with no dimensions? Like, if there's a lot of text in the minipage, does that mean that it would be typeset over text beneath it (on the first run, when markers are undefined).\

Comment: And finally, how do the definitions from the `\zz` macro get read in to the file? And when? I figured you'd have to use a `\read` or something to read them in.

Comment: @Beelzebielsk I'm writing to the aux file which is always read in at begin document, yes on the first run the size is arbitrarily set to textheight and will overprint, but as its size is hidden it doesn't affect the rest of the document. search this site for `\pdfsavepos` there are hundreds of examples of this

Comment: I did not know that the aux file is always read in at the start. Where can I learn more about it? I'm not seeing anything about it in tex by topic or in the texbook. Is the aux file a latex thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87136/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-beelzebielsk).